# How did Led Zeppelin get their name?

Tags: names, led-zeppelin

How did Led Zeppelin get their name? Was it something they just came up with together, or was it based off of something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> One account of how the new band's name was chosen held that Moon and Entwistle had suggested that a supergroup with Page and Beck would go down like a "lead balloon", an idiom for disastrous results. The group dropped the 'a' in lead at the suggestion of their manager, Peter Grant, so that those unfamiliar with the term would not pronounce it "leed". The word "balloon" was swapped for "zeppelin", a word which, according to music journalist Keith Shadwick, brought "the perfect combination of heavy and light, combustibility and grace" to Page's mind.

[Reference on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin)